# How to load a partial view by clicking a row in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two partial views, one is _UserList and the other one is _UserDetail and both of them are shown in index.

```
[index.cshtml]

@Styles.Render("~/Content/PagedList.css")

<h2>UserManagement</h2>

<hr />
    <div id="UserList">
        @Html.Partial("_UserList")
    </div>
<hr />
    <div id="UserDetail"></div>
<hr />
```

I already have a link named Details that is implemented with Ajax.ActionLink to show the detail in every rows.

[image: 1]

And the link's source code is:

```
[_UserList.cshtml]

@Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "UserDetail", new { userId = item.ID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "UserDetail" })
```

After click "Details", _UserDetail will be shown under _UserList.

[image: 2]

Now, I want to implement a clickable row that can load _UserDetail with a parameter: item.ID when I click on a row of the table in _UserList.

I have tried a lot of ways but I still cannot implement it successfully.

Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Did you reference the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js into the View?

Comment: you can use jtable plugin

Comment: @AlexandrePires, thanks a lot. I have referenced it and the partial view works normal with Details link. I just need to change it to clickable row but I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: @Rica, I will try it later, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to implement this feature with jQuery.
And the source code is as below:

```
<table class="table table-hover>
    @foreach (var item in Model.TlmAbstractPagedList)
    {
        <tr data-id="@item.TlmId" class="clickableRow">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(u => item.DateStart) ~ @Html.DisplayFor(u => item.DateEnd)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(u => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var product in item.ProductInformation)
                {
                    <ul>product.ProductNameWithId</ul>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<script>
    $('.clickableRow').click(function () {
        var targetRow = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'TlmManagement/TlmReport',
            data: { tlmId: targetRow },
            method: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#TlmDetail").empty();
                $("#TlmReport").empty();
                $("#TlmReport").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

I assign data-id to every row and the class click function will check this data-id to find out which row is being clicked and then make display of the data.
Hope this source code will help someone.